# Assign the extracted row to another variable

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of size say 30*200. I want to extract each row and assign it to another variable so that I can access each row. I want it to be displayed as `p(1)=a(1,:)` and so on. I want to extract all the 30 rows. I dunno how to do this in MATLAB as it is generating the error

> both the vectors must be of the same length.

Comment: What did you try? Always post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
p = a(1,:); %// p is now 1-by-200 row vector
```

In a loop

```
for ii=1:size(a,1)
    p = a(ii,:); %// get the ii-th row
    %// manipulate the row here...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see an immediate advantage in writing something like `p(r)` instead of `a(r,:)`, also this does not seem possible. You can, however, store vectors in cell arrays. They can be accessed by curly bracers, so that an access by `p{r}` is possible.

```
a = rand(30, 200); %// the 30x200 matrix a
p = cell(size(a,1), 1); %// initiate the cell of needed size

%// iterate over rows r
for r = 1:size(a,1)
    p{r} = a(r,:); %// now p{r} == a(r,:)
end
```